# css double color background hack

Tags: css, css-float

Hi friends is there any possible to get a double color background like this as 100% width and height like this

Here is the sample image:

[Sample Image http://www.mediaserveit.com/demo/vivek/resources/question.png](http://www.mediaserveit.com/demo/vivek/resources/question.png)

(sample)white in left hand side rest of them are other color.

if i did with div's means

```
.left{
    float:left;
    width:30%; 
    background-color:#fff;
 }

.right{
    float:right;
    width:70%;
    background-color:#B97A57;
}
```

which made height problem.it increases depends upon the contents on the div's.if i use min-height means it also changed on different screens.if there any hack to set like this background in html body!because i need it in full screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a gradient as background.

```
body{
    background: #fcfcfc; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #fcfcfc 30%, #6b1717 30%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(30%,#fcfcfc), color-stop(30%,#6b1717)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #fcfcfc 30%,#6b1717 30%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #fcfcfc 30%,#6b1717 30%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #fcfcfc 30%,#6b1717 30%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #fcfcfc 30%,#6b1717 30%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#6b1717',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */    
}
```

Gradient generated using: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/guE5L/

Comment: Thank you @Cristy If in left side instead of white am having gradient rest of them are white means what should i do.!

Comment: You can use the generator http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create any gradient you want :)

Comment: Keep in mind that old IE proprietary `filter` produces the completely different result, which is unlikely suitable here. Also, there is no need to specify `-ms-linear-gradient` since all shipped versions of IE10 support W3C syntax (only the early betas required `-ms-`).